# Assigning attributes to undeclared variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

This piece of code

```
uniqueInteger.count = 0;
function uniqueInteger() {
    return uniqueInteger.count++;
}
console.log(uniqueInteger());
console.log(uniqueInteger());
```

produces the following output:

```
0
1
```

How it happens that this code is executed, as when assigning `count` attribute on the first line `uniqueInteger` is not declared yet?

Comment: I suspect because you've created an implicit global, and it's been hoisted, so the function hoists, then it has a property assigned to it

Comment: It's because *declarations* happen before anything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of [function hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

Basically when you declare a `function`, it's conceptually moved to the top of your code *(although this is not what the browser is literally doing, check the previous docs for more information about that)*, therefore, we can rewrite your code to the following flow:

```
function uniqueInteger() {
    return uniqueInteger.count++
}
uniqueInteger.count = 0;
console.log(uniqueInteger()) // 0
console.log(uniqueInteger()) // 1
```

Comment: Your link contradict your explanation: `Conceptually, for example, a strict definition of hoisting suggests that variable and function declarations are physically moved to the top of your code, but this is not in fact what happens`

Comment: @GabrielBleu you're right, I modified the answer to make it a bit more clear